# Vim how to change font without having the font installed on the computer?

Tags: vim, fonts

I was wondering how to change the font used in gvim to Inconsolata without having the font installed on the system (to C:/Windows/Fonts) I have the font on a usb drive and I want to make vim portable, so I have the 2 files on the usb drive.

How can I use "set guifont=Inconsolata" to make it work without having to install it? I tried "set guifont=D:/Inconsolata.otf" and "set guifont=D:/Inconsolata" but it still doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to put this in the wrong place, but I see a lot of VIM questions going around here that aren't closed at all, so I thought this was a suitable place to ask my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't work. Not like that at least.

The font has to be "installed" from the system's (and thus Vim's) point of view.

On Windows XP, you can "install" a font without admin privileges following this method:

1. Navigate to `C:\WINDOWS\Fonts`.
2. *File* → *Install…*
3. Choose the font on your USB stick.
4. Uncheck *Copy…*.
5. Hit *OK*.

I have no idea if/how you can do it on Vista/7/8.

Comment: Ah, I see, that's unfortunate. Thanks anyways though!

Comment: How is that unfortunate?

Comment: The fact that he can't use it from the USB, he has to install it first.

Comment: It takes less than 1 minute.